# Kali (WSL2) installing kali-linux-default: Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: linux, installation, packages, aptitude, fetch

After `apt-get install kali-linux-default` I'm getting:

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 wce all 1.42-beta-0kali3
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 webshells all 1.1+kali6
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 windows-binaries all 0.6.9
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 wce all 1.42-beta-0kali3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 webshells all 1.1+kali6
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 windows-binaries all 0.6.9
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/non-free/w/wce/wce_1.42-beta-0kali3_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/w/webshells/webshells_1.1+kali6_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/non-free/w/windows-binaries/windows-binaries_0.6.9_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried following (which didn't help):

```
apt autoremove
apt-get update --fix-missing

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Do you have any idea how to complete the installation for the rest of the archives? Thank you

Comment: It is complaining about the internal IP address. Does the machine have unfettered internet?  Are you prefixing the commands with sudo  ?  It does not show above. You do need to enter   sudo apt-get update and authenticate.

Answer (score 3):

I already figured it out. I had to use `https://` instead of `http://` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: also works to fix the same issue for "kali-linux-everything"